# Not accessing the button title I want even though I use the right tag in swift

Tags: swift, button

I want to create a tic tac toe style board with x's and o's.  This first part works and changes the buttons code successfully.

```
   func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        print("Button \(sender.tag) tapped")
        var tag = sender.tag
        print(sender.currentTitle!)
        if sender.currentTitle! == "" {


            sender.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
            sender.setTitle("X", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        } else if sender.currentTitle! == "X"  {
            sender.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
            sender.setTitle("O", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }else if sender.currentTitle! == "O"  {
            sender.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
            //sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
            sender.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }
    }
```

This gives me the right button but no access to the title already in it.

```
   @IBAction func deleteAnswers(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

      var totalBoxes = getTotalNumberOfBoxesInGrid()
        var tag = Int()

        for tag = 1; tag <= totalBoxes; tag++ {

                let button = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton
                button!.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
```

In fact in the second section changing the empty string ""  (no title) to a letter, say "P" simply prints a "P" over the existing title.  How do I get access the the original title?

Comment: I woke up this morning with the solution to my problem in my head (Don't you love it when that happens.) It is a solution that works but it is not the answer to my question.  I simply use "buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)" only to get the tag #.  Then instead of using sender.setTitle i set up a new UIButton this way using the tag# I got from the sender.  "if var button = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton" and use that to set the title.  When the buttons are written to that way the delete works.

Answer (score 0):

I woke with this solution in my head and it works.  However it is a solution and not strictly the answer to the question: i.e. how do I get access to a button title set up with send.setTitle. When the "sender" is only used to get a tag# and button titles are set up as I set them up below, delete and other functions needed to access the information work.

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
        print("Button \(sender.tag) tapped")
        var tag = sender.tag
        print(sender.currentTitle!)

 if var button = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton {

    if button.currentTitle! == "" {


        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("X", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myUserValuesDictionary[globalAppD.newPuzzle.name]![tag] = 1
        } else if button.currentTitle! == "X"  {
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("O", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myUserValuesDictionary[globalAppD.newPuzzle.name]![tag] = 2
        }else if button.currentTitle! == "O"  {
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "chalkduster", size:  fontSizeTag)
        //button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myUserValuesDictionary[globalAppD.newPuzzle.name]![tag] = 0
        }
    }
}
```